# Validate an HTML embed code using PHP or javascript or PHP framework (Zend)

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, embed, validation

just a simple question.. 
Is there any good practices to validate an HTML embed code?
fyi, I am using Zend Framework and prototype+scriptaculous right now.. 
it would be great if someone could give a clue around that environment.

Thank you! ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to allow user to input HTML, and then display it on your website, a really great solution is [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

It takes any kind of "sort of" HTML code as input, and returns valid-HTML, allowing you to specify which tags and attributes must be allowed -- all others will be removed.

This way, if your users input not-valid HTML, you'll still get valid HTML *(less risk of destroying your layout when outputing it)*, and if you only specify a couple of non-dangerous tags and attributes, it's a great plus for security.

If you want to try it without having to integrate it in your application, there's a [demo page](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php) available, btw.

For instance, if I input something like this :

```
<p>
this <b>is a<i>test</b></i>
with a not <em>closed tag
and a <a href="http://google.com" onclick="alert('bouh');">link</a>
and some <script type="text/javascript>alert('script');</script>
</p>
```

The HTML I get as [output will be](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter[AutoFormat.AutoParagraph]=0&filter[AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI]=0&filter[AutoFormat.Linkify]=0&filter[AutoFormat.PurifierLinkify.DocURL]=%23%25s&filter[AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp.Exceptions]=td%0D%0Ath&filter[AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp]=0&filter[AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty]=0&filter[Null_CSS.AllowedProperties]=1&filter[Core.CollectErrors]=0&filter[Null_HTML.Allowed]=1&filter[Null_HTML.Doctype]=1&filter[HTML.TidyLevel]=medium&filter[URI.DisableExternalResources]=0&filter[Null_URI.Munge]=1&html=%3Cp%3E%0D%0Athis+%3Cb%3Eis+a%3Ci%3Etest%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%0D%0Awith+a+not+%3Cem%3Eclosed+tag%0D%0Aand+a+%3Ca+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%22+onclick%3D%22alert%28%27bouh%27%29%3B%22%3Elink%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0Aand+some+%3Cscript+type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%3Ealert%28%27script%27%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E&submit=Submit) :

```
<p>
this <b>is a<i>test</i></b>
with a not <em>closed tag
and a <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
and some </em></p>
```

ie tags are OK (closed, in the right order), the script tag has been removed, and so has the onclick attribute of the link.

Comment: beat me too it. One of the best solutions i know of. There are a few classes on phpclasses that does the same thing but this is probably more recent +1

Comment: Thanks dude!! was looking for this solution! ^^

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit hazy but it sounds like you are getting html submitted and you want to redisplay it on your site.

Your best bet is to figure out a set of accepted HTML, and strip all tags that don't match.